# Issue assigning a SED to a variable

Tags: sed, bsd

I am working on a BSD machine and what I am attempting to do is assign a variable the output from a SED command that uses a variable as input. Been working on this for 3 days, tried multiple different things, and always end up with './subscript: ${sed ...}: Bad substitution' error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
TMPEX=${sed "s/\\\\\\/\\\\/g" <<$TMPEX}
```

TEMPEX originally contains

```
C:\\Windows\\System32\\wininit.exe
```

and I would like to replace the double backslashes with single backslashes so that TMPEX contains:

```
C:\Windows\System32\wininit.exe
```

What am I missing?

Comment: @Stem: you can (and _should_) edit your question to fix problems, rather than just acknowledge the issue in comments.  I've done it for you this time — please do it yourself in future.  (It might be different if your edit would invalidate an answer; in this case, it would not.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Using `sed` and a shell which understands here-strings:

  ```
  TMPEX="$(sed 's/\\\\/\\/g' <<< "$TMPEX")"
  ```
- Or, still using `sed`, for a shell which does not understand here-strings:

  ```
  TMPEX="$(echo "$TMPEX" | sed 's/\\\\/\\/g')"
  ```
- Or even better, if the shell understands pattern substitution:

  ```
  TMPEX="${TMPEX//\\\\/\\}"
  ```